# I need help figuring out how to add values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying add hours entered into the fields that precede H and M. I know that I only need it to work once for the H and I can then just apply the same code to the M. I hope that it is not too confusing. Here is a snippet of what I have.

```js
function sum() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h2").value);
  var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h3").value);
  var num4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h4").value);

  var result = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;

  document.getElementById("h5").value = sum;
}
```

```html
<td><h5>Current</h5></td>
<td><span><input id="h1" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h2" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M          
<td><span><input id="h3" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h4" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h4" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" readonly>H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" readonly>M <button type="button" name="clickbtn" value="Calculate" onclick="sum()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Input values are strings. Convert to number to add them. OR use [valueAsNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of helping you see how to simplify things and make your code more readable and less bulky, I revised some things and corrected a few along the way.

Your regex eventListener worked great, but was the same for each input element, so I removed it, and instead set up a loop to go through each hour and minute element and apply it. It reduced your code quite a bit, and you can see how it works. In your actual page, you will want to make sure you run that loop after the HTML or in a window.onload function, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
 let h = document.querySelectorAll('.h, .m');
 for (let x = 0; x < h.length; x++) {
  h[x].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
  });
 }
}
```

Your `type` tags had css classes in them (I think) which I separated. Also, the `size` didn't need to be repeated, just use a css style.

You didn't need all the id tags - just the ones to show the total. Instead, I gave each element a class - `h` for hour and `m` for minute. Now, using a querySelector loop, you can add them all up. This also has the benefit of allowing you to add as many hour/minute inputs as you want and not have to adjust the javascript.

In the adding function, it's important to convert the input value into a number. I used the shorthand `+` operator right in front of the value which tells javascript to convert that into a number. `Number(value)` or `parseInt(value)` or `parseFloat(value)` would all work for that as well. I also used a ternary expression (shortened if statement) `+h[x].value || 0` to check if the value existed, if not use a zero.

```js
let h = document.querySelectorAll('.h, .m');
for (let x = 0; x < h.length; x++) {
  h[x].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
  });
}



function sum() {
  let h = document.querySelectorAll('.h');
  let m = document.querySelectorAll('.m');
  let total_h = total_m = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < h.length; x++) {
    total_h += +h[x].value || 0;
  }
  for (let x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
    total_m += +m[x].value || 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("total_h").value = total_h;
  document.getElementById("total_m").value = total_m;
}
```

```css
.h,
.m {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h5>Current</h5>
    </td>
    <td><span><input type="number" class="h justify-content-center"  >H</span><span><input type="number" class="m justify-content-center" >M
          <td><span><input type="number" class="h justify-content-center" >H</span><span><input type="number" class="m justify-content-center">M          
          <td><span><input type="number" class="h justify-content-center" >H</span><span><input type="number" class="m justify-content-center">M
          <td><span><input type="number" class="h justify-content-center">H</span><span><input type="number" class="m justify-content-center" >M
          <td><span><input id="total_h" type="number" class="h  justify-content-center"  readonly>H</span><span><input type="number" id="total_m" class="h  justify-content-center"  readonly>M </td></tr></table>
          
          <button type="button" name="clickbtn" value="Calculate" onclick="sum(this)">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- `id="h5"` was not present in the HTML
- `value = sum;` sum is not a variable, `result` is the value you meant
- Some of HTML tags are not correctly terminated, the browser doesn't care tho

Now this works:

```js
function sum() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h2").value);
  var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h3").value);
  var num4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h4").value);

  var result = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;

  document.getElementById("h5").value = result;
}
```

```html
<td><h5>Current</h5></td>
<td><span><input id="h1" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h2" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M          
<td><span><input id="h3" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h4" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">M
<td><span><input id="h5" type="number justify-content-center" size="5" readonly>H</span><span><input type="number justify-content-center" size="5" readonly>M <button type="button" name="clickbtn" value="Calculate" onclick="sum()">Calculate</button>
```

But you probably want to mark all inputs that need to be summed with a class like:

```
<input class="h_sum">
<input class="m_sum">
```

And write a function like this:

```
const makeSum = (class) => [...document.querySelectorAll(class)].reduce(
  (acc, x) => acc + parseFloat(x.value, 10), 0);
document.getElementById("h5").value = makeSum('.h_sum');
document.getElementById("h6").value = makeSum('.m_sum');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the property `innerHTML` or `innerText`.
`document.getElementsByTagName("h5").innerHTML = sum;`

Oh, The `<h5>` tag has no `id` property.